# Count number of complementary pairs in array

Tags: python, arrays, count

I am rookie with `python` and have question about counting pairs in array that complement to some certain number.

**Example** 
Given an integer array `A` find all the complementary pairs in `A` that sums up to a provided value `K`, so for example given the array `[2, 45, 7, 3, 5, 1,8,9]` and an integer `K = 10` the result must be `3` because the input array contains `[9, 1] [7, 3] [8, 2]`

Here is the code finding complementary pairs

```
def find_pairs(x, sum):
    s = set(L)
    for i in L:
        diff = 10-i
        s.remove(i)

        if diff in s:
           print i, diff

L = [2, 45, 7, 3, 5, 1, 8, 9]
sum = 10
find_pairs(L, sum)
```

How can I add count command at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a simple counter variable

```
def find_pairs(list_, sum_):
    s = set(list_)
    pairs = 0

    for i in list_:
        diff = sum_ - i
        s.remove(i)

        if diff in s:
            pairs += 1

    return pairs
```

Or you can use a helper list for storing pairs if you also want to know the pairs

```
def find_pairs(list_, sum_):
    s = set(list_)
    pairs = []

    for i in list_:
        diff = sum_ - i
        s.remove(i)

        if diff in s:
            pairs.append([i, diff])

    return pairs

L = [2, 45, 7, 3, 5, 1, 8, 9]
pairs = find_pairs(L, 10)
print pairs
>>> [[2, 8], [7, 3], [1, 9]]
print len(pairs)
>>> 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy:

```
A = np.asarray(A)
np.count_nonzero((A[None, :] + A[:, None]) == K) // 2
```

Comment: Whats the complexity of that? I'm not sure what does  `(A[None, :] + A[:, None]) == K` do, but is that efficient? Does it check all the possible combinations of that list?
That would be O(n^2) then, am i right?